# Soft lines after html elements and a specific letter showing wrongly in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, html

The previous week I moved my local server with my site from a computer with Windows to another one with Linux.Thats when i noticed that there are some weird soft lines after elements and the letter "Λ" (which is greek) showing like its damaged.Its important to mention that if i zoom out the letter is displayed correctly.Also i visited my site from a PC with windows and everything seems fine. I hope that these photos will help you understand better the problem.

[Soft Lines + Letter Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOMSv.jpg)
[Soft Lines + Zoom Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdozD.jpg)

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

I have read somewhere (don't remember much where exactly) that many problems of the sort are caused by the encoding.
So you might want to ensure that your characters are UTF-8.
Have a look at [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/)

Hope it helps

Comment: I have included <meta charset="utf-8"> in my html file and saved it with UTF-8 encoding also.